# What proposals have been made to amend the U.S. Constitution to make it mention God?

Tags: united-states, religion, reference, us-constitution

Many State constitutions in the United States mention God:
[image: State constitutions mentioning God/divine]

But the U.S. Constitution does not.*

**What proposals have been made** (say in the 19<sup>th</sup> century) **to amend the U.S. Constitution to make it mention God?**

<sup>*One explanation is given ([*The Strange Spirit of Solange Hertz – Expanded*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9703) p. 88, PDF p. 97): Given that the religious aspects were in the Declaration of Independence, "It would seem fitting that references to Almighty God be reserved for a special document rather than sticking Him in between paragraphs on the workings of government."</sup>

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes. I made it bold.

Comment: Please edit the title to ask a question

Answer (score 6):

This can be answered by looking at the wikipedia article on [proposed amendments to the US constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proposed_amendments_to_the_Constitution_of_the_United_States). There is a specific mention of several attempts to incorporate Christian religious references :

> The Christian Amendment, first proposed in February 1863, would have
> added acknowledgment of the Christian God in the Preamble to the
> Constitution.[8] Similar amendments were proposed in 1874, 1896, and
> 1910 with none passing. The last attempt in 1954 did not come to a
> vote.

Comment: Phew... I didn't know it was actually *that* bad... 8-O

Comment: The answer is NONE.  Thankfully, The Establishment Clause has remained unchanged for over 230 years.

Comment: @Alex: The question was about *proposed* amendments. This answer points out that such proposals had been made, repeatedly, so "none" isn't the answer.

Comment: @Alex The Establishment Clause doesn't prohibit the federal government from recognizing God and that civil authority comes from Him; it prohibits the creation of a national religion.

Comment: The recognition and acknowledgement of God as the Foundation of "Civil Authority", was a Jeffersonian concept expressed in The Declaration of Independence; however, The Declaration of Independence and The Constitution-(more specifically...The Bill of Rights), were distinct documents, whereby the former, was more philosophical in tone, while the latter was more juridical and legalistic in tone.  The purpose of The Establishment Clause was to prohibit a national religion, though inherent and implicit within that prohibitive language, was the omission of any explicit referencing to God.